# 48 pieces on one board

Tags: rules, chess-variants, chessboards

I saw this picture on the Internet.

[image: chess]

I am wondering if there is any way to play on this board. Does anyone know what the rules are for this type of chess?

Answer (score 5):

It is one of many forms of [three-player chess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-player_chess), apparently called 3 Man Chess. Rules are explained [here](http://www.3manchess.com/).